# Import and export single collection in mongo using cmd

Tags: mongodb, import, mongodb-query, export

i try to import database collection but i found import whole database not single collection

```
mongorestore -d db_name dump_folder_path
```

so here is solution to import and export single collection in mongodb cmd

Comment: You can also use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` OS com,and-line tools to export and import the database or a single collection. For using with large datasets these are a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Import

```
mongoimport --db Mydatabase --collection mycollection --drop --file ~/var/www/html/collection/mycollection.json
```

For Export

```
mongoexport --collection=mycollection --db=Mydatabase --out=/var/www/html/collection/mycollection.json
```

Hope this works :)